# Seleção de campo input com JQuery

Tags: html, jquery, mvc

tudo bem?

Conseguem me dar uma ajuda relacionada a seleção do texto digitado por um usuário em um formulário?
Já tentei algumas soluções que encontrei aqui, mas não funcionaram. Também já tentei abordagens diferentes com Javascript puro, mas não tive sucesso.

O formulário está dentro de uma View MVC do Asp.Net e preciso pegar os dados digitados pelo usuário na página para enviar para a Controller.

A função enviarDados() está com as informações de atribuição/envio para a controller. Debugando eu consigo ver que a função está sendo chamada com sucesso, porém as variáveis que deveriam estar com os valores digitados estão "null".

Formulário:

```
  <p class="text-center">Dados para cadastro: </p>
            <form>
                <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                    <label for="nome">Nome: </label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nome" placeholder="Nome.">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                    <label for="email">E-mail: </label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="E-mail.">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                    <label for="telefone">Telefone: </label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="telefone" placeholder="Número de contato.">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                    <button type="submit" class="botaogrande btn btn-primary" onclick="enviarDados()">Cadastrar</button>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Tentativa se seleção com jQuery:

```
var dadosNome = $("#nome").text();
var dadosTelefone = $("#telefone").text();
var dadosEmail = $("#email").text();
```

Desde já, muito obrigado.

Comment: Olá Bruno, tente capturar os valores com este método : (var dadosNome = $("#nome").val(); ).

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, muito obrigado. :)

Comment: Seja bem-vindo Bruno, não deixe de fazer um tour pelo site. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour Marcar resposta como aceita https://i.stack.imgur.com/jx7Ts.png Porque marcar uma resposta como aceita https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079

Answer (score 1):

**Com Jquery**

- .val() - é um método jQuery usado principalmente para obter os valores dos elementos dos formulários, como input, select e textarea.
- .text() - é um método jQuery cujo resultado é uma string contendo o `texto combinado` de todos os elementos dentro do elemento referenciado.
- .html - é um método jQuery usado para obter o `conteúdo HTML` do primeiro elemento referenciado

  ```js
  console.log($("#divNome").html());
  console.log($("#divNome").text());
  console.log($("#nome").val());
  ```

  ```html
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <div style="display:none" id="divNome" class="col-md-12 form-group">
    <label for="nome">Nome: </label><span>Value do input já preenchido!</span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nome" placeholder="Nome." value="Bruno">
  </div>
  ```

> Esses métodos também podem ser usados para definir o conteúdo dos elementos

```js
$("#texto1").html('<a href="#">Este é um link com a função .html</a>');
 $("#texto2").text('<a href="#">Este é um link com a função .text</a>');
  $("#idInp").val('Este é value do input com a função .val');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="texto1"></div>
<div id="texto2"></div>
<input id="idInp" size="34">
```

**Com JavaScript**

```js
var valor = document.getElementById("nome").value;

console.log(valor);
```

```html
 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nome" placeholder="Nome." value="Bruno">
```

> A propriedade `value` define ou retorna o valor do atributo value de um campo de texto.